# Applying symbology to raster layer in ArcPy without using symbology layer (layer file)?

Tags: arcpy, raster, layers, symbology, rgb

I have a raster layer with 3 unique values (1,2,3) and I want to apply a unique color to each using RGB values or hex codes, without the use of a symbology layer (layer file).

Is it possible to create a color map or symbology layer (layer file) entirely in ArcPy?

I want my code to add the raster layer to the map with the symbology I want (as opposed to random), but I don't want to use a pre-created symbology layer (layer file) or colormap - I would like the colors to be selected entirely in ArcPy, if possible.

```
arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(cat, "cat")
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management("cat", "cat.lyr", "ABSOLUTE") 
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0]
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, "cat.lyr", "TOP")
# this is where I want to apply unique colors to each pixel value (pixel values are: 1,2,3)
# but I don't want to use add colormap or apply symbology from layer, unless the symbology
# layer or colormap can be created entirely in arcpy. I would like the color decisions
# to be made entirely in arcpy, without having to make a symbology layer or colormap 
# in the GUI
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
del mxd, df
```

something like this?

```
colormap = open("colormap.clr", "w")
colormap.write("1 70 137 102\n")
colormap.write("2 255 176 59\n")
colormap.close()
```

Comment: Are you wanting to change the pixel values?  Or just make it display differently?

Comment: Pixel values can remain, I just want to change the colors

Comment: Change the colours of what?  If it's not in a layer, how are you seeing it?

Comment: I do have a layer - what I'm trying to do is change the colors in arcpy without using a symbology layer to do so, unless there's a way to create a symbology layer in arcpy with the colors I want

Comment: Look at the tool Apply Colormap http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000009w000000 and http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t0000002r000000 about creating the colormap file, that sounds like what you're after. Note there is also a Delete Colormap tool to reset the raster back once you're done.

Comment: A colormap would work, but is it possible to create the colormap entirely in arcpy? I'm not opposed to using a symbology layer if it's possible to create entirely in arcpy.

Comment: Yes, read the links (carefully), the color file is just a text file that can be written 'on the fly' by python then applied. All you need to know is what RGB values to assign to each unique value. Note: raster must be an integer type (int8, int16 etc..) you cannot apply a colormap to a float without Int-ing it first. It would be best to apply the colormap *before* adding it to the map or the modifications may not be recognized. Can you give examples of RGB values you want to use?

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks. I'm not sure what the correct syntax would look like in arcpy, though. RGB samples: 70 137 102; 255 176 59

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
# I'm assuming cat is the full path to a raster
# or a raster object

TempDir = os.environ.get("TEMP") # Your temp folder
ColFile = os.path.join(TempDir,"TEMP_CLR_FILE.clr")

with open(ColFile,'w') as ColWrite:
    ColWrite.write("1 255 0 0\n") # 1 = red
    ColWrite.write("2 0 0 255\n") # 2 = blue

arcpy.AddColormap_management(cat,input_CLR_file = ColFile)

arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(cat, "cat")
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management("cat", "cat.lyr", "ABSOLUTE") 
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*")[0]
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, "cat.lyr", "TOP")
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
del mxd, df
os.remove(ColFile) # clean up your mess
```

Write the colorfile on the fly with python file writing.. [it's only a text file](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009t0000002r000000). Then remove the temp file after it has been applied; the file is not linked to the raster.

[AddColormap](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-colormap.htm) has some specific requirements that need to be addressed.. please read the docs carefully as there's a few traps that will prevent this method from working.

Comment: worked perfectly, ty!